# GNU Parallel - --joblog only logging last job

Tags: bash, parallel-processing

this is a followup from [GNU Parallel - which job failed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24370243/gnu-parallel-which-job-failed)

I'm asking parallel to output its status to a logfile test.log, but it's consistently only logging the last job it tried to run.

```
weedom@host1: ~/$ parallel --tag --nonall  -j8 --joblog test.log -S host1,host2 uptime 
host2   10:41:17 up 36 days, 20:45,  1 user,  load average: 0.00, 0.00, 0.00
host1         10:41:17 up 22:34,  3 users,  load average: 0.06, 0.11, 0.04
weedom@host1: ~/$ cat test.log
Seq     Host    Starttime       Runtime Send    Receive Exitval Signal  Command
1       host1        1403689277.067  0.519999980926514       0       0       0
weedom@host1: ~/$
```

this is with "GNU parallel 20130522"

Comment: Weird.  This works for me: `parallel --tag -j 1 --joblog test.log -S host01,host02 /usr/bin/uptime  ::: "" ""` but this doesn't: `parallel --tag -j 2 --nonall --joblog test.log -S host01,host02 /usr/bin/uptime`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You experience a bug that was fixed in version 20130922.